# Is there a need to check for null after casting?

Tags: solidity, type-casting

Example:

```
MyReceiver my = MyReceiver(_to);    // To is an arbitrary address user provided
my.someFunction();                  // Do I need to check for my == null before calling?
```

Strange enough I do not see anyone doing so.

Answer (score 0):

In solidity there is no such thing as a "null" (at least you can check if the passed address isn't a special one like 0x00)

```
MyReceiver my = MyReceiver(_to);
```

this line will store _to address in the variable `my` and indicates to the compiler that we are dealing with a contract (to construct the calls following the ABI). Its not like OOP objects!!

check it using this snippet code :

```
MyReceiver  c=MyReceiver(0x1234);
function test() view returns (address) {
 return c;
    }
```

if you want t check if the contract exists you can use instead

```
extcodesize(a)
```

to check if the size of the code at the given address is 0 or not.

Comment: Thanks Badr, how about the contract does exist, but doesn't has the someFunction() implement?

Comment: this will trigger the fallback function in the called contract. otherwise the call will fail. besides if you find the previous answer helpfull think of accept it ;) we try to minimize bumped questions.